# Does Material-UI's Select component use setTimeout when closing and if so, why?

Tags: reactjs, select, material-ui, cypress

Does Material-UI's Select component use a timeout or other time function then closing? I have been trying to find the implementation of the code and also tried debugging but I can't find an answer to this.

I need to know this due to an issue I ran in to when writing GUI-tests using the Cypress testing framework and its clock()-method on the Select component.

The clock method is used to override time-functions like date, setTimeout and clearTimeout (https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/clock.html#Syntax).

When using this without specifying that I only want to override Date the Select component doesn't close as it should. The actual dropdown closes but the invisible backdrop div (#menu-.presentation) stays put thus hiding all the other components when cypress want to continue the test run.

Without the clock the test works fine apart from the date related errors that is expected. This lead me to think that the Select somehow uses a timeout, even though I have been unable to find any proof. I would really like to understand this behavior.

I'm not using the Native select.

The dependencies related have the following versions:

"@material-ui/core": "4.3.2"

"cypress": "3.2.0"

"cypress-testing-library": "2.4.0"

Comment: You can check out the implementation of the Select in your project on: node_modules\@material-ui\core\Select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking through the code is complicated by the number of different components involved, but if you dig through all of them, you will eventually find `setTimeout`.

- `Select` [uses SelectInput](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.5.2/packages/material-ui/src/Select/Select.js#L41)
- `SelectInput` [uses Menu](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.5.2/packages/material-ui/src/Select/SelectInput.js#L352)
- `Menu` [uses Popover](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.5.2/packages/material-ui/src/Menu/Menu.js#L132)
- `Popover` [uses Grow](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.5.2/packages/material-ui/src/Popover/Popover.js#L113) as its default `TransitionComponent`.
- `Grow` [uses setTimeout](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.5.2/packages/material-ui/src/Grow/Grow.js#L106)
- `Grow` also uses `Transition` from `react-transition-group` which also [uses setTimeout](https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group/blob/v4.3.0/src/Transition.js#L317).

Comment: Thank you! That's what I was looking for!